# Identify Points in GLM residual plots in R

Tags: r, plot, glm, logistic-regression, outliers

How can I go about identifying the points in the residual plots that I get by running `plot(glm.object)` in R?

I understand how `identify()` works but where can I get the x and y values required for it for these plots?

I also know about `boot::glm.diag.plots` but I find that fact that it forces all 4 plots onto one screen rather irritating.

Comment: You can get the manually by doing `glm.object$residuals`

Comment: You can also create your own residuals vs. fitted plot by simply doing: `plot(glm.object$fitted.values, glm.object$residuals)`

Comment: Thanks... I'm most specifically interested in the residulas vs. leverage plot.  How can one find the leverage?

Comment: `hatvalues(glm.object)`. Also see [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476475/how-to-produce-leverage-stats).

Comment: It's interesting that this question was upvoted even though OP did not provide a remotely reproducible example, and, having been a member for more than a year, should certainly know better.